# Royal Slider and Lightbox, thumbnails container doesnt get width

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Im having a bit of trouble of getting a Royal Slider working in a lightbox - If you take a look at this page: http://www.wearewebstars.dk/frontend/Test/boerneunivers2.html - And then click the arrow, where it says "Hvad er Myanmar" - Then it opens a lightbox with a gallery - However, the container of thumbnails only get a width of 36px - But the if I resize the window, then it gets the full width of all the thumbnails, and places the thumbnails correctly - Any ideas? I've tried resizing the window programmaticly, but cant get it to work: 
The script I have is:

```
$(".toggle-gallery-8").on("click", function(event){
                $('#gallery-8').royalSlider({
                    fullscreen: {
                      enabled: true,
                      nativeFS: true
                    },
                    controlNavigation: 'thumbnails',
                    autoScaleSlider: true, 
                    autoScaleSliderWidth: 960,     
                    autoScaleSliderHeight: 850,
                    loop: false,
                    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
                    navigateByClick: true,
                    numImagesToPreload:5,
                    arrowsNav:true,
                    arrowsNavAutoHide: true,
                    arrowsNavHideOnTouch: true,
                    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
                    usePreloader: true,
                    fadeinLoadedSlide: true,
                    globalCaption: true,
                    globalCaptionInside: false,
                    updateSliderSize: true,
                    thumbs: {
                      appendSpan: false,
                      firstMargin: true,
                    }
                });
                $('#gallery-8').royalSlider('updateSliderSize', true);
                /*if($(".window.fade.in").length() > 0){
                    $(".window").trigger("resize");
                }*/
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on the developer site I found that it's a known issue that sometimes happens.

> If slider size is dynamic: try to resize your browser, if after
>   resizing layout looks correctly - this is the issue.
>
> If slider size is static: change size of root slider element via
>   Chrome Web Inspector or Firebug and resize browser window. Or just run
>   jQuery('.royalSlider').royalSlider('updateSliderSize', true); in
>   console and see if it fixes your problem.

Doc: http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-issues/slider-content-area-shrinks

You can try to call `updateSliderSize` method:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.royalSlider').royalSlider('updateSliderSize', true);
}, 500)
```

after the slider definition, the setTimeout is needed to handle a little timing issue.

Comment: I tried adding it to the script, but without any luck :( - Still doesnt work - I've updated the script

Comment: Can be a timing issue, try to use a setTimeout(function(){$('.royalSlider').royalSlider('updateSliderSize', true);},500)